# How to explode map datatype in Hive OR how to give multiple aliases in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Suppose I query :

```
select explode(map_column_name) as exploded from table_name
```

I get this error:

> The number of aliases in the AS clause does not match the number of
>   columns output by the UDTF, expected 2 aliases but got 1

and I googled the error and got to know that to give more than one alias , we use stack function .. 
How to use stack function along with explode function so that I eventually explode map datatype and also give 2 aliases at a time?

Kindly bear with me as I am a beginner and learning Hive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With default columns names

```
select explode(map) from table_name
```

With aliases

```
select explode(map) as (mykey,myval) from table_name
```

**Demo**

With default columns names

```
select explode (map('A',1,'B',2,'C',3))
;
```

---

```
+-----+-------+
| key | value |
+-----+-------+
| A   |     1 |
| B   |     2 |
| C   |     3 |
+-----+-------+
```

With aliases

```
select explode (map('A',1,'B',2,'C',3)) as (mykey,myvalue)
;
```

---

```
+-------+---------+
| mykey | myvalue |
+-------+---------+
| A     |       1 |
| B     |       2 |
| C     |       3 |
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thankyou Dudu for your help .. but your first query gives me an error .. I have already mentioned the error . And also is there any way we can use both explode() and stack() functions together .. If not , then why not we can .

Comment: when we use explode() , we have to use aliases . In your first query , there is no alias .. So , it will anyhow not execute without alias though the error this time will be different from what I have mentioned

Comment: As I am too not using computer now . So please dont mind If I let you know the exact error  tomorrow morning once I execute your first query ..

Comment: I am using Hive 0.10 and when I use explode() without  alias , the error which I get is  --> FAILED: SemanticException 1:7 UDTF's require an AS clause. and the same error I get when I use your first query .. However your second query works perfectly fine and I get the desired result .. THANKYOU Dudu

Comment: Hive 0.10 was released on January 2013, 4.5 years ago(!)

Comment: So you mean that now the upgraded versions support explode() without aliases ?

Comment: Yes. What I'm putting in my answers are copy-pasted results from actual executed queries.

Comment: Ok Dudu . Then I accept your answer and your help is always appreciated :)